# Improving Machine learning model for trading and trend prediction

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, adaboost

I am working on making predictions and decisions based on stocks and crypto data.

First I implemented a decision tree model and I had Model Accuracy: 0.5. After that I did some research and found out that decision tree is not enough and I tried to improve it with random forest and adaboosting.

After that I noticed that I have 3 above mentioned algorithms with the same training and test data, and I get three different results.

Now the question is if it is possible to make the three algorithms work together by combining them in some way and benefit from the previous result?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

You can combine classifiers, yes. This is considered an *ensemble*. It's a bit weird to make an ensemble from a decision tree and a random forest, though. A random forest  *is* an ensemble of decision trees. That's why it's called a forest.

Comment: okay thank you, and how to combine the random forest results with adaboost ?

Comment: Adaboost itself isn't a classifier; it's a way to train classifiers. You probably should check out an AI course; you can't just grab a number of algorithms and expect the combination to make sense